# Cannot create cluster role in GKE even though I am owner and admin

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, rbac, google-kubernetes-engine

After creating a new GKE cluster, creating a cluster role failed with the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "./role.yaml":
clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "secret-reader" is forbidden: 
attempt to grant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], 
APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], 
APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], 
APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]}] user=&{XXX@gmail.com  
[system:authenticated] map[authenticator:[GKE]]} ownerrules= . 
[PolicyRule{Resources:["selfsubjectaccessreviews" 
"selfsubjectrulesreviews"], APIGroups:["authorization.k8s.io"], Verbs: 
["create"]} PolicyRule{NonResourceURLs:["/api" "/api/*" "/apis" 
"/apis/*" "/healthz" "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1" "/swagger.json" 
"/swaggerapi" "/swaggerapi/*" "/version"], Verbs:["get"]}] 
ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

My account has the following permissions in IAM:

> Kubernetes Engine Admin
>
> Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin
>
> Owner

This is my `role.yaml` (from the [Kubernetes docs)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole):

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: secret-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

According to the [RBAC docs of GCloud](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control), I need to

> create a RoleBinding that gives your Google identity a cluster-admin role before attempting to create additional Role or ClusterRole permissions.

So I tried [this](https://projectriff.io/docs/running-on-gke-with-rbac/):

```
export GCP_USER=$(gcloud config get-value account | head -n 1)
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding
--clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=$GCP_USER
```

which succeeded, but I still get the same error when creating the cluster role.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 11):

According to [Google Container Engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control) you must first create a RoleBinding that grants you all of the permissions included in the role you want to create.

## Get current google identity

```
$ gcloud info | grep Account

Account: [myname@example.org]
```

## Grant cluster-admin to your current identity

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding myname-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=myname@example.org

Clusterrolebinding "myname-cluster-admin-binding" created
```

Now you can create your ClusterRole without any problem.

I found the answer in CoreOS [FAQ / Troubleshooting](https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html) check it out for more information.

Comment: this does not work. I get the error "clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "mail@mydomain.com" cannot create clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope: Required "container.clusterRoleBindings.create" permission.

Comment: You need to be granted the `Kubernetes Engine Admin` role in GKE, it's not enough anylonger with only `Editor`.

Answer (score 4):

@S.Heutmaker`s comment led me to the solution.

For me, the solution was to create the cluster-admin-binding with the correct casing on the email address. Check the casing in error message or google cloud console IAM

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding myname-cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=MyName@example.org
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct solution. Is the GCP_USER obtained the same as the `XXX@gmail.com` username in the role creation error message?

Comment: Yes, the GCP_USER is the same email address.

Comment: Does this include casing? FirstLast@gmail.com is not the same as firstlast@gmail.com

Comment: @S.Heutmaker After almost an hour of frustration, your tip on case sensitivity just fixed my issue. Thanks for the keen eye.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the casing right, try to add both googlemail domain variants (i.e. `@gmail.com` and `@googlemail.com`). For me `gcloud info | grep Account` returned `<name>@googlemail.com` but I had to create a clusterrole binding with `<name>@gmail.com` for the command to work.